# which path for a file to appear in the xhtml of a jsf app

Tags: jsf, xhtml, path

common.pde in the canvas tag is not found at runtime:

xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="processing-1.4.1.js" />
        <canvas data-processing-sources="common.pde"></canvas>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

=> common.pde sits in the "Web pages" folder of my JSF 2.0 application. What is the correct method to specify its path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any relative paths (i.e. those not starting with `http://` or `/`) in the HTML source code (as generated by JSF) are relative to the current request URI (as you see in browser's address bar).

So, if the current request URI is:

```
http://example.com/contextname/somefolder/page.xhtml
```

then the `common.pde` reference as you've there expects it to be in:

```
http://example.com/contextname/somefolder/common.pde
```

A leading `/` which brings you to domain root as in `/common.pde` would expect it to be in:

```
http://example.com/common.pde
```

Going one folder up `../` as in `../common.pde` would expect it to be in:

```
http://example.com/contextname/common.pde
```

Being in a subfolder as in `canvas/common.pde` would expect it to be in:

```
http://example.com/contextname/somefolder/canvas/common.pde
```

I think it makes now sense? I guess that your concrete problem is caused because your JSF page is in a subfolder, or that you've mapped the `FacesServlet` on a prefix pattern such as `/faces/*` instead of a suffix pattern such as `*.xhtml`.